# Which items in EVE Online are classified as 'Meta 0' items?

Tags: eve-online

Basically, which items in EVE are considered as 'Tech 0' and thus have a purchasable original blueprint sold by NPCs on the market?

I know examples includes the standard **1MN Afterburner I**

I can't seem to be able to find any resources with this information; basically, a list of Meta 0 items.

Comment: Well, virtually everything, that's kind of the point of EVE. The exceptions are fairly obvious, things raw materials (ore, minerals, planetary materials, salvage, etc...) and certain other items that can't be directly used like tags and trade goods. Skill books are the only thing I can think of off-hand that can be used by players as is and can't be manufactured. In any case, unless things have changed since I played you should be able to find the complete list of blueprints in the blueprint section of the trading screen at any station. I don't think there are any contract-only blueprints.

Comment: Try market sites and trading programs.

Answer (score 3):

To piggyback on what @Ross Ridge said in the comments above AND according to the [EVE Online Forums](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=93686) -

> Meta 0 items are flat t1. So, Tracking Disruptor I, 200mm Autocannon
>   I, Light Electron Blaster I.
>
> Meta 1-4 are named (200mm 'scout' Autocannon I, balmer series tracking
>   disruptor...)
>
> Meta 5 is t2
>
> Meta 6+ are faction/deadspace/officer.

So as Ross said, "Virtually Everything" :)

I hope this helps out!  Fly Safe!

Comment: A simple way to look at it is if there is Blueprint origonal avalable for it on the market, it is either Tech 1 (meta 0) or Tech 2 (meta 5). If it doesn't cost in the billions, it is probably a meta 0 module.

Comment: I doubt you'll find a T2 BPO module on the market, as a blueprint needs to be packaged to be sold, which also means it has never been researched, copied or used for manufacturing, which i reaaaaally think is statistically impossible as of now. Unless CCP plan to release T2 BPOs, which would instantly spawn the pitchfork mob everywhere.